# array of function pointer returning output before incrementing the value in the function

Tags: arrays, function, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int show();
int showadd(int);
int(*arr[3])();
int (*(*ptr)[3])();

int main(){
    int result;
    arr[0]= show;
    arr[1]=showadd;
    ptr = &arr;
    result = (**ptr)();
    printf("printing the value returned by show : %d",result);
    (*(*ptr +1))(result);

}
int show()
{
    int a = 65;
    return a++;
}
int showadd(int b)
{
    printf("\nAdding 90 to the value returned by show: %d", b+90);
}
```

when i printed the result which is pointing to int show() which has a++ the answer printing is 65 instead of 66. what is causing this behavior.

Comment: Here the culprit is a++. when I returned a+1 it is working fine but when I use the increment operator value is not getting incremented.

Comment: `a++` increments `a` AFTER reading the value that will be returned.  So use `++a` instead.